# Debugging firewall error in SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am facing the following error from a while .When I am trying to debug any stored procedure ,it is giving the debugging firewall error .Help me to solve .

[image]

Comment: Use this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646024.aspx

Comment: Is this instance local or remote?

Comment: Local Instance @Sankar

Comment: Try with turn off the firewall.

Comment: is it fixed?. why i am asking is i also have this issue... :P. If so then i also try this.